# Scala unapply in traits

Tags: scala

How can I use unapply in traits?

```
import play.api.libs.json.Json

trait Json[T] {

  implicit val jsonFormat = Json.format[T]

}
```

Gives compile error:

```
No unapply function found
```

Can i somehow force the compiler to bound T to case class so I can make use of unapply?

Answer (score 1):

This is the requirement for which Scala's [extractors](http://www.artima.com/pins1ed/extractors.html) exist. An extractor is a method called `unapply` that is usually defined in an object (typically a companion of the type in question). It is used to destructure a value into its constituents.

Here's an example (quite contrived):

```
object Extractor1 {
  def unapply(a: Any): Option[(String, Int)] =
    Some(a.toString, a.toString.length)
}

object ExtractorUse {
  import Extractor1._
  def use {
    "23 skeedo!" match {
      case Extractor1(str, length) => printf("str=\"%s\"; length=%d%n", str, length)
    }
  }
}
```

In use:

```
scala> ExtractorUse.use
str="23 skeedo!"; length=10
```

If the extractor returns `None`, the match attempting it will fail. Likewise if the arity of result is not consistent with the pattern varibles supplied in the `case` clause.

There is also a counterpart for extracting sequences, `unapplySeq`. See the Programming in Scala link for details